# Constraint to limit the scope of an attached dependency property

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to add a constraint to an attached dependency property so that it only can be applied to a specific type, something in the metadata?

If not, is it meaningful to explicit type the static Get-and Set-methods of the attached DPs?

**Example:**

If I have for example the following declaration:

```
public static int GetAttachedInt(DependencyObject obj) {
    return (int)obj.GetValue(AttachedIntProperty);
}

public static void SetAttachedInt(DependencyObject obj, int value) {
    obj.SetValue(AttachedIntProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachedIntProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachedInt", typeof(int), 
   typeof(Ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

would it be meaningfull to change it as follows, to only apply it to TextBoxes?

```
public static int GetAttachedInt(TextBox textBox) {
    return (int)textBox.GetValue(AttachedIntProperty);
}

public static void SetAttachedInt(TextBox textBox, int value) {
    textBox.SetValue(AttachedIntProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachedIntProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachedInt", typeof(int), 
   typeof(Ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

My question is, because this leads to an inconsistence, because GetValue and SetValue could be used anymore for any type and also in markup is no possibility to limit the attachement.

What I did formerly was that I added an exception into the PropertyChanged handler and raised there an exception that only the types xy are allowed.

What do you think?

Comment: Good question... hopefully my new answer resolves it.

Comment: For the metadata, I have wished another answer but I also have seen nothing. For The declartion of the access-methods, I think its a question of policy. If it's common sense to do it like this, I will do. But for me its a little like close the balcony with with a big lock but leave the main door unlocked. But at least the set-and get methods show the purpose of the attached dp.
I will use your recommendation but continue to check the destination type in the PropertyChanged-handler. So a user will receive an exception in the designer if he tries to use the DP on a wrong control.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe all you need to do in order to restrict the target type of attached properties is change the definitions of the `GetPropertyName` and `SetPropertyName` methods.

Example:

```
public static int GetAttachedInt(MyTargetType obj)
{
    return (int)obj.GetValue(AttachedIntProperty);
}

public static void SetAttachedInt(MyTargetType obj, int value)
{
    obj.SetValue(AttachedIntProperty, value);
}
```

where `MyTargetType` can be any type inheriting from `DependencyObject`.

Comment: Well, not so wrong... I tried with Visual Studio 2013 and it gives the following error if you try to attach the property to something else: **The attached property "AttachedInt" can only be applied to types that are derived from "TextBox".**

Comment: Benoit is right. In VS2013 XAML intellisense will prevent you from attaching it to a non-supported element. I don't use ReSharper.